# iphone opencv - template matching

Tags: iphone, xcode4, opencv, computer-vision

i've implemented this OpenCV build into my iphone project:

http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

It builds successfully and i know how to capture an image with my camera, grayscale it and show it on an imageview.

But what i'd like to do is templatematching with the image that i captured (with the camera) against an template image.

I have both images grayscaled, but i just don't get how the 'matchTemplate' works. This is what i have so far:

```
cv::Mat grayFrame, grayImg, output;

// This is the template image which i store in a cv::Mat and
// after that i grayscale the image
UIImage *testImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"qr.png"];
cv::Mat tempMat = [testImage CVMat];
cv::cvtColor(tempMat, grayImg, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);


// Convert captured frame to grayscale
cv::cvtColor(_lastFrame, grayFrame, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

// Having trouble here...
cv::matchTemplate(grayFrame, grayImg, output, CV_TM_CCORR_NORMED);


// Display result
// This already works for both the captured image and the template image
camView.image = [UIImage imageWithCVMat:grayFrame];
```

The problem with this code is, is this line:

cv::matchTemplate(grayFrame, grayImg, output, 1);

I'm not sure if i'm doing it right. Because i don't get a result back in 'output' like "MinMax" to get the positions of the found match... Am i even passing the right variables to the matchTemplate function...??

Anyway, can someone please tell me what i'm doing wrong and how to make this work?

- edit - 
  Added a screenshot of my variable 'output'
  [image]

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The matchTemplate() function returns a matrix whose values represent the probability of the match on every pixel of the original image. It contains floating-point data and has the same size (width/height as the input). To extract the position of the most likely match, you must run the minMaxLoc() function over the result.

Comment: Thanks, i just found out about that method by reading this topic: http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/77992 -- 

But i still don't understand how that gives me the location, because it only gives me the minValue and the maxValue -> minMaxLoc(output, &minVal, &maxVal);

Any idea how to get that back??

Comment: void minMaxLoc(InputArray src, double* minVal, double* maxVal=0, Point* minLoc=0, Point* maxLoc=0, InputArray mask=noArray()). It returns both value and position. send a reference to two points, and it will set them with to the desired values.

Comment: I think my build isn't right then, because i don't have that method where i can pass the minLoc/maxLoc Points. http://i39.tinypic.com/4lniok.png -- What library are you using for iOS?

Comment: don't worry, there are some overloaded methods, just call it with the parameters described above, and it will find the good one.

Comment: You're right. It indeed points to the overloaded method like you said. So i'll mark your answer as the correct one since it is. But i do hope you can help me out with one last thing. Cause i have the pass a Point structure, but it gives me an error because of that: -- no known conversion from Point * (aka Point *) to Point * (aka Point_<int> *) -- I tried creating it like: -- Point[] res1; -- and -- Point *res1; -- and -- Point res1; --.. But all fails.  Any idea what i'm doing wrong..?? Thanks anyway for all you help!

Comment: As for the points, it seems a problem of pointers. And you should make sure you init them correctly. Like that: Point p(1,1); Point* pp = &p; Point p2 = *pp; Check also this pointer tutorial http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

Comment: I figured it out. Had to do it like this: cv::Point res1;